# Как замокать сервис в тестах?

Tags: flutter, mock

Типичный наверно вопрос(
Пытаюсь замокать сервис:

```
class MockTestService extends Mock implements TestService{}

void main() {
  group('Many test', () {

    testWidgets('test navbar', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      if (locator.isRegistered<TestService>()) {
        locator.unregister<TestService>();
      }
      var w = MockTestService();
      when(w.GetText()).thenReturn("test");
      locator.registerSingleton<TestService>(w);

      await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
      expect(find.text('test'), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

Но падает на `when(w.GetText()).thenReturn("test");`
Пишет: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`
Что делаю не так?